# Buffer based on shapefile not lining up with Landsat as precisely as needed in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, buffer, landsat, zonal-statistics

I am trying to measure beach quality of different coastal districts in Jamaica in ArcGIS Pro. To do this I created a 100m buffer from an administrative shapefile by dissolving the shapefile into one polygon and then making a polyline feature from the outline of the island. Then, using a Landsat 5 raster, I attempted to calculate wavelength values for each coastal district's coastline as proxied by the 100m buffer, using the zonal statistics table.

The problem is that for many districts, the raster does not line up perfectly with the shapefile, resulting in me getting a wavelength range that starts at 0 for the coastline, which is inaccurate. How can I go about making sure that my raster perfectly fits the administrative shapefile that I am using to make the buffer so that I get correct wavelength  values?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be just one of those "you can't fix it" situations. See [How Long Is the Coast of Great Britian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Long_Is_the_Coast_of_Britain%3F_Statistical_Self-Similarity_and_Fractional_Dimension). Pixel size and sea height at the moment the image was taken play into the equation, as well as obliqueness and other data capture issues.